# Working with files in bat

Tags: windows, templates, for-loop, batch-file

I have to show the filenames using given template. I've written the following code:

```
if "%2" == ""  (
    echo "Missing second argument!"
    set /p FileName="Input file name template ('*', '?' are allowed): "
    set /p FileType="Input file type ('text', 'bat', 'all' only): "

    if FileType == "all" (set FileType = "*")
) else (
    set FileType="%2"
)


echo %DirSearch%\%FileName%.%FileType%

for %%i in (%DirSearch%\%FileName%.%FileType%) do  (echo "Thats it: %%i")
```

If the second argument is empty, I ask user about filename template, extension (if its equal to 'all' I rewrite it's value as '*'.

Now the first trouble is that it isn't rewritten. When I put 'all' the 'FileType' is still 'all' after setting it to '*'. Why?

And echo shows up:

```
"C:\Folder"\test.all
"Thats it: "C:\Folder"\test.all"
```

How to interpretate it as single value and use in `for`?

---

New code:

```
if "%2" == ""  (
        ...
    if "%FileType%" == "all" (set FileType=*)
) else (
        ...
)

set result=%DirSearch%\%FileName%.%FileType%
echo %result%

for %%i in (%result%) do  (echo "Thats it: %%i")


// echo %result%:
"C:\Data\test"\test.all
// in for cycle
"Thats it: "C:\Data\test"\test.all"
```

The right string should be: "C:\Data\test\test.all"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not testing the value of `FileType` in the correct manner. Also, you are not setting the new value in the correct manner. The code should read

```
if "%FileType%" == "all" (set FileType=*)
```

Otherwise, you are just comparing the strings "FileType" and "all", which of course never succeeds.

Aside: You also seem to have some error in the code that sets `DirSearch`; there's an extra trailing double quote there that shouldn't be.

Comment: This doesn't rewrite `FileType`, after if it's still 'all'.

Comment: @Ockonal: It turns out that there must be no spaces around the `=` as well, I edited the answer accordingly. Also, you don't need quotes around the values when *setting* them.

Comment: okay, thanks, now it replaces it. But how to generate right string for `for` cycle?

Comment: @Ockonal: Please edit the question and clarify what you mean "right string". I already said there's an extra quote there, and you don't show the code that puts it in.

Comment: Hm, `DirSearch` is taken with "%~f1", maybe it's not a string

Comment: @Ockonal: It should be `%~f1`, without any quotes.